# Why JSTL tags inside select are ignored by Jsoup

Tags: java, jsp, jsoup, jstl

I want to parse a jsp page which has c:Foreach inside select tag as shown below(for drop down) using Jsoup.

```
<select  name="test" multiple="multiple" size="4>   
        <c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
            <option value="${item.Name}"> ${item.Nmae} </option>
        </c:forEach>   
</select>
```

But when I parse and check for child Nodes then c:ForEach element is Missing from child Nodes.
 Is there any way to get the c:Foreach element as child Node ?

Comment: Is Jsoup processing the raw JSP file directly on your file system, or is it processing the generated HTML returned by your servlet container?

Comment: inspect your jsp page in the web browser, do you notice how there are no JSTL tags there? That's why Jsoup is ignoring them. Because it never sees them to begin with.

Comment: @Andreas Jsoup is processing jsp file directly from local file system